# Model of PA in which every subset of $N$ extends to a definable set

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $M$ be a model of Peano Arithmetic.

Show that $M$ has an elementary extension $M^*$ such that for every $X \subset M$, there is a set $X^* \subset M^*$ such that $X^* \cap M = X$ and $X^*$ is definable in $M^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle one set $X$, simply add a new constant symbol $c$ and then let $T$ be the theory consisting of the elementary diagram of $M$ together with the sentences stating that $k$ is in the set coded by $c$ (such as via binary digits or whatever coding you like), iff $k\in X$.

This theory is finitely consistent, and so it has a model $M^*$ by compactness. Let $X^*$ be the set coded by $c$ in $M^*$. The theory is precisely designed so that $X=X^*\cap M$, as desired.

Now, one can handle all sets $X\subset M$ simply by having lots of constants $c_X$, one for each set. The theory is still finitely consistent, and the argument works the same way.

A remark: you asked for $X^*$ to be *definable*, but I took you to mean definable with parameters. In my solution, for example, $X^*$ is definable from parameter $c$. In general, without parameters, it is not true even for the one-set case, since any definable subset of $M^*$ restricts to a definable subset of $M$, when $M^*$ is an elementary extension of $M$.

It would be an interesting question to give up on elementarity of the extension $M\subset M^*$, but ask in the one-set case for $X^*$ to be definable without parameters in the extension.

Comment: Re: the last paragraph, that seems doable: pick some formula $\varphi(x)$ such that for all disjoint finite sets $F, G\subset\mathbb{N}$, the theory $PA\cup\{\varphi(n): n\in F\}\cup\{\neg\varphi(m): m\in G\}$ is consistent (which takes a bit of work but is fine). Then for any $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, there is some $M\models PA$ with $\{x: \varphi(x)\}^M\cap\mathbb{N}=X$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. It seems that one can also use the result that: every function can be computable http://jdh.hamkins.org/every-function-can-be-computable/, applied in $M$.

Comment: I was under the impression that $M$ is any model of PA. Not just the standard model, not even a countable model.

Comment: Yes, I had in mind to apply that result inside $M$, using the largest consistent fragment of PA (which will include the actual PA).

Comment: There is an interesting related open question in models of arithmetic:  is there a Borel model of arithmetic coding every subset of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @JDH I doubt it - such a Borel model has some set of natural numbers as a Borel code, and I bet from this + a diagonalization argument we could produce a set of naturals which doesn't extend to any definable element of the model (in particular note that attaching a set of natural numbers to a definition-with-parameters can be done in a Borel way). But I don't immediately see how to do this, to be fair, so maybe it can occur.